# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

I am creating an API which first checks for `test_set_id` in one table then if found get more data from another table.

If the test_set_id which is given is not present / not correct it sends an error and also when no test for the creator id is found

So, I have the following error. The response which I get is correct and as I want but to understand the internal working more properly I want to understand the error and how to avoid it.

My understanding till now is I am not handling the promise functions properly and something is missing.

I don't think that my implementation is wrong, any ways I would be glad if anyone can help me.

**Error is as follows :**

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:482:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/siddhant/Projects/CreateTestAPI/create-test-api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/siddhant/Projects/CreateTestAPI/create-test-api/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at connection.query.then.then.then (/home/siddhant/Projects/CreateTestAPI/create-test-api/routes/create-test.js:228:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
GET /admin/test-overview 200 2.635 ms - 72
```

**API code is as follows**

````
   const corp_id = request.body.creator_id;
   const academic_id = request.body.academic_id;
   var connection = new promise_database.Database();
   var result = {};

   const statement_1 = `SELECT id, academic_id, candidate_id, created_at, question_id
   FROM m_edu.custom_test_history_students WHERE academic_id = '${academic_id}'```

   const statement_2 = `SELECT test_set_id
   FROM m_edu.test_created_history WHERE test_creator_details_id = '${corp_id}'`

   connection.query(statement_2)
      .then(rows => {
         if (Object.keys(rows).length === 0) {
            result.status = "Not OK";
            result.message = "No Tests has been created till now";
            result.code = 142706
            response.send(result)
         } else {
            count = 0
            for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(rows).length; i++) {
               if (rows[i].test_set_id == academic_id) {
                  count++
               }
               if (count > 0) {
                  return connection.query(statement_1);
               } else {
                  result.status = "No Such Test";
                  result.message = "Please check again for test_set_id"
                  response.send(result)
               }
            }

         }
      }, error => {
         console.log(error);
         result.status = "Server Error";
         result.message = "Please Contact Server Admin";
         result.code = 142708;
         response.send(result);
      }).then(rows => {
         console.log(rows)
      }, error => {

      }).then(() => {
         response.send("Done")
      }).catch (error => {
         console.log(error) //line 228
      })
});
````

If the test_set_id matches, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case when you haven't matched rows you are trying to send 2 responses. First one in the if statment `response.send(result)` and the second one in the last `then` `response.send("Done")`.

Comment: Thanks. The extra then was causing the problem.